# Can we tweak description of Mortarboard to clarify that rep has to come from votes?

Tags: bug, badges, user-interface

The description of the Mortarboard badge is "Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day".  This isn't actually quite right; the rep has to come from other people's votes, acceptances, and bounties, not from anything you do (like accept answers or have edits approved).  Adding two words to this description would eliminate this confusion: "Earned at least 200 reputation *from others* in a single day".  Can we make this change?

Comment: This is a small thing, but when I noticed a few hours before midnight UTC that I had 195 rep for the day I thought I might get it by making up those last 5 points myself.  Oh well.

Comment: Tag this [meta-tag:bug] rather than [meta-tag:feature-request]? It seems like an *incorrect* description, which should be fixed. No?

Comment: @msh210, good point.  Done.

Comment: Does anyone know how this affects Epic and Legendary?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd [guess it's the same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), but I'm not in a position to know from experience. :-)